# python RE findall() return value is an entire string

Tags: python, html, regex, web-crawler

I am writing a crawler to get certain parts of a html file. But I cannot figure out how to use re.findall().

Here is an example, when I want to find all ... part in the file, I may write something like this:

```
re.findall("<div>.*\</div>", result_page)
```

if result_page is a string `"<div> </div> <div> </div>"`, the result will be

```
['<div> </div> <div> </div>']
```

Only the entire string. This is not what I want, I am expecting the two divs separately. What should I do?

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it.

Answer (score 7):

Quoting [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=greedy),

> The `'*'`, `'+'`, and `'?'` qualifiers are all greedy; they match as much
>   text as possible. Adding `'?'` after the qualifier makes it perform the
>   match in non-greedy or minimal fashion; as few characters as possible
>   will be matched.

Just add the question mark:

```
In [6]: re.findall("<div>.*?</div>", result_page)
Out[6]: ['<div> </div>', '<div> </div>']
```

Also, you shouldn't use RegEx to parse HTML, since there're HTML parsers made exactly for that. Example using [BeautifulSoup 4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

```
In [7]: import bs4

In [8]: [str(tag) for tag in bs4.BeautifulSoup(result_page)('div')]
Out[8]: ['<div> </div>', '<div> </div>']
```

Comment: Why shouldn't I use RegEx to parse HTML? What is the correct way?

Comment: @alvinzoo there're always HTML parsers e.g. Beautiful Soup for Python. You might want to read [this famous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/2301450).

Answer (score 5):

`*` is a [**greedy**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedy) operator, you want to use `*?` for a **non-greedy** match.

```
re.findall("<div>.*?</div>", result_page)
```

Or use a parser such as BeautifulSoup instead of regular expression for this task:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
soup.find_all('div')
```